# rotate the world

Tags: world

I just started in Blender. How do I rotate the world? I´ve been trying and so far just can make the object rotate. I would like to use a tool witch I can grab the world and rotate it, like in Google earth. And then, be able to aproximate or put away.

Is it possible?

Comment: what "world" are you talking about? an object, the background in cycles, the whole 3D view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this use the middle mouse button, which will allow you to rotate the scene world.

Comment: tks. Genius....

Comment: @MarcusFigueiredo Great! Don't forget to tick and mark as solved.

Comment: where I do this?

Comment: @MarcusFigueiredo on the left side of my answer you will find a Tick between up/down arrows. The tick is to mark the answer as solved, and the arrows are to upvote and downvote the answer.

Comment: @MarcusFigueiredo as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFhXo.png